# Use ViewComponents from RazorClassLibrary in .net 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

Can I use ViewComponents from RazorClassLibrary?
I did not find anything on the Internet with an implementation in .net 6.
I need to make a separate RCL with ViewComponents for Asp.Net.

When the components are in the same project with the application, then everything works, but as soon as they are transferred to a separate project, the application does not see the components.

I made an application to test the functionality of such a structure.

Solution Structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DlHg.png)

I insert the ViewComponent in the index:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("ProductList",
                         new {
                         maxPriority =  5,
                         isDone = false  }
                         )
```

I also added the path to the library project in Program.cs.

```
builder.Services.Configure<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>(options =>
{
    var libraryPath = Path.GetFullPath(
        Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "..", "TestLib"));

    options.FileProviders.Add(new PhysicalFileProvider(libraryPath));
});
```

From this I get an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: A view component named 'ProductList'
> could not be found. A view component must be a public non-abstract
> class, not contain any generic parameters, and either be decorated
> with 'ViewComponentAttribute' or have a class name ending with the
> 'ViewComponent' suffix. A view component must not be decorated with
> 'NonViewComponentAttribute'.    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponents.DefaultViewComponentHelper.InvokeAsync(String
> name, Object arguments)    at
> AspNetCore._Views_Home_Index.ExecuteAsync() in
> C:\Users\podzolkin\source\repos\ExampleAspNetApp\AspNetTestApp\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:line
> 5    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage
> page, ViewContext context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage
> page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext
> viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext
> actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData,
> ITempDataDictionary tempData, String contentType, Nullable`1
> statusCode)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext
> context, ViewResult result)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

But I have a suffix in the class name.

ProductListViewComponent.cs

```
public class ProductListViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        private readonly DemoContext db;

        public ProductListViewComponent(DemoContext context)
        {
            db = context;
        }

        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string template, int maxPriority, bool isDone)
        {
            var items = await GetItemsAsync(maxPriority, isDone);
            return View(template, items);
        }

        private Task<List<Product>> GetItemsAsync(int maxPriority, bool isDone)
        {
            return db!.Products!.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to my question. Perhaps this will help someone.
I added such lines to the .csproj RCL.

```
<ItemGroup>
        <SupportedPlatform Include="browser" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <EmbeddedResource Include="Views\**\*.cshtml" />
        <EmbeddedResource Include="ViewComponents\*.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>
```